# How do I specify a daemon to start with alternate emacs version with emacsclient

Tags: emacsclient, start-up, bash, emacs-daemon

I have found this script from [here](https://medium.com/@bobbypriambodo/blazingly-fast-spacemacs-with-persistent-server-92260f2118b7)

```
#!/usr/bin/env zsh
# Checks if there's a frame open
emacsclient -n -e “(if (> (length (frame-list)) 1) ‘t)” 2> /dev/null | grep t &> /dev/null
if [ “$?” -eq “1” ]; then
 emacsclient -a ‘’ -nqc “$@” &> /dev/null
else
 emacsclient -nq “$@” &> /dev/null
fi
```

that seems nice for starting the daemon with `-a ''` only if there is not a server up. However at my work, our emacs and emacsclient intended to be used are prefixed with `abc`, so we have `abc_emacs` and `abc_emacsclient`. There are older Emacs in the system with the regular names.

So how do I modify a command like `emacsclient -a '' -nqc somearg` so that it starts the server in the case of no server being up with `abc_emacs` instead of `emacs`?

Comment: You could add symlinks `$HOME/bin/emacs{,client} -> /path/to/abc_emacs{,client}`, and put `$HOME/bin` in your standard PATH.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `-a` specifies the editor that should be started if there is no emacs server started yet (the so-called "alternate editor). If the empty string is passed, as in the script above, `emacs --daemon` is run and emacsclient tries to connect to it (see `man emacsclient` or `M-: (info "(emacs) emacsclient Options")` within emacs). Unfortunately, in your case, `emacs --daemon` obviously runs the wrong Emacs. Hence, we'd like to specify an alternate editor that will start `abc_emacs --daemon` and then connect to it. I think the easiest method is to simply create a script that will do that for us.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

abc_emacs --daemon
emacsclient "$@"
```

Call it, say, `abc_emacs_helper` (hopefully that won't collide with any existing programs), make it executable and place it somewhere in your `$PATH`. Then you can replace `emacsclient -a ''` with `emacsclient -a 'abc_emacs_helper'`).